# Searching for all properties of a document using aggregation and project with change in date format in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My database model looks like

```js
{
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  projectId: { type: String, required: true },
  createdAt: { type: Date, required: false },
  updatedAt: { type: Date, required: false },
};
```

`createdAt` is of format `2021-10-07T11:16:44.988Z` and I wants at the time of fetching data from database date format should be `2022-02-25`. so I wrote query to database like this:

```js
const { id } = req.params;
const participantList = await ParticipantModel.aggregate([
  { $match: { projectId: id } },
  { $limit: limitInt },
  { $skip: skipInt },
  {
    $project: {
      Date: { $dateToString: { format: '%Y-%m-%d', date: '$createdAt' } },
    },
  },
]);
```

I got result as below:-

```
  { _id: 6218e52f43ec044180e69b84, Date: '2022-02-25' },
  { _id: 6218e5f543ec044180e69b97, Date: '2022-02-25' },

]
```

**Expected result**

```
[
  { _id: 6218e52f43ec044180e69b84,email:'xyz@gmail.com', name:'xyz',projectId:"01A", Date: '2022-02-25',updatedAt: 2022-02-25T14:18:23.708Z},
  { _id: 6218e5f543ec044180e69b97, email:'abc@gmail.com', name:'abc',projectId:"01B",Date: '2022-02-25' , updatedAt: 2022-02-25T14:21:41.313Z,},
]
```

How to solve this? Thank you for your help.

Comment: use [$addFields](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) instead of `$project`

Answer (score 0):

In `$project` guide of [mongodb docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/), set value to 1 each field if you want to show or 0 to hidden:

```
const { id } = req.params;
const participantList = await ParticipantModel.aggregate([
          {$match:{projectId:id},},{$limit:limitInt},{$skip:skipInt},{$project:{
            Date: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$createdAt" } },
            email: 1, name: 1, projectId: 1, updatedAt: 1
          }}
```